# How to scatter spark executor pods in different nodes during the same application?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Currently I'm running spark application on k8s, I wish to scatter spark executor pods in different nodes during the same application as much as possible

I notice that executor pods have been labled automatically by some.

[image]

I suppose this could be done by using `podAffinity`, but these lables are generated during runtime, like `spark-app-name` and `spark-app-selector`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pod template file using `--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile=<your_file_here>` as discussed [in the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template) and specify your pod affinities. I found a semi-example [here](https://dev.to/stack-labs/my-journey-with-spark-on-kubernetes-in-python-2-3-5e8j), maybe this helps :)

There was a [discussion](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/36358) about this on Spark's Github and the conclusion was that using a pod template file is the preferred solution.